# How do I get a website's content without the superfluous?

Tags: c#

I have a string that contains the content of a website, for instance (overview, insert tags and content in your mind)

```
$string = '<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
    <title>Some title
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>Navigation
    <br><div>CSS</div>
    <br><div>JavaScript</div>
    <br>Advertising
    <br><div>Content</div>
    <br>Navigation
    <br>Advertising
    <br>Inprint
    <br>
  </body>
</html>'
```

How do I get the content without the superfluous? By content, I do not mean the word "Content" but whatever real content a website has.

For instance, in a forum, I want the forum's entries without navigation, tags, advertising.

I tried `string s = Regex.Replace(string, "<.*?>", String.Empty);` which is just stripping the tags, but not getting the content.

Are there some patterns on websites that repeat and can be exploited that help me get to the content without the clutter?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the superfluous". Can you post what your expected output would be?

Comment: Use the Html Agility Pack to parse HTML.

Comment: @smead updated.

Comment: Your first mistake is to use a **one-dimensional** data structure tool like **regex** for a data structure that is inherently _hierarchical_

Comment: @MickyD Be helpful.

Comment: I am.  Don't take it personally

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HTML Agility Pack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack) NuGet package. It is pretty flexible and you can become very specific with what you want to achieve through it.

Here is an example on how to get all the hyperlinks in a page:

```
HtmlDocument document2 = new HtmlDocument();  
document2.Load(@"C:\Temp\sample.txt")  
HtmlNode[] nodes = document2.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a").ToArray();  
foreach (HtmlNode item in nodes)  
{  
    Console.WriteLine(item.InnerHtml);  
}
```

There are more examples [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9b86d4/getting-started-with-html-agility-pack/).

Comment: While being a good start, it does not address the main problem. The main problem is, how to filter the content, in other words, what to use in `SelectNodes` or in the `foreach`-loop. I tried `if (item.InnerText.Length > 250 && !item.InnerHtml.Contains(">"))` but it wasn't that easy. Then I found that the values of certain `attributes` of tags like `div` and `span` contain `full` or `article`, so I used this. Still not very satisfying.

Comment: @pdee Please define `content` and on your question provide an example.